# Cordova - Refused to load the image (blocked:csp)

Tags: cordova, content-security-policy, whitelist

I am trying to show images but got this errors:

Someone know why it blocks my images?

[image]

[image]

I have this in my index.html to get access to the server:
[image]

Comment: You'll have to add `https://smx123test.000webhostapp.com` to your `img-src` instead of `style-src`...

Comment: And please always post any code or error message as text and not as a screenshot if possible. A screenshot is not searchable and harder to work with...

Comment: it works, thanks. Ok, next time i will put text better than screenshots, thanks for all.

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad it worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments you'll have to add the url `https://smx123test.000webhostapp.com` to your `img-src` instead of `style-src`.

For futher information refer to the [Mozilla CSP docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy#Directives). They offer an overview over the different directives and further details on every directive.